# Working with nested Panels

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

Trying to build out a GUI for my game but no matter what layout I work with I can't get the nest of panels to do what I like

My goal is this 
http://i182.photobucket.com/albums/x202/NekoLLX/CharGenmockup-1.jpg
http://i182.photobucket.com/albums/x202/NekoLLX/CharGenmockup2.jpg

And Building off the Mad ones excelent revision I've got my left side as i like it but now the right eludes me

The general idea is that clicking on the title bars of the left menu will colapase (set visible to false) the content panes associated with them

```
//http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430922/working-with-nested-panels

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JaGCharCreation  {

//set inital size of window
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int initalWidth = (int) screenSize.width - 50;
int initalHeight = (int) screenSize.height - 50;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JaGCharCreation ();
}

//set up thread safe invoking for GUI
public JaGCharCreation () {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new TestPane());
            frame.pack();
            //frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            // Give the frame an initial size.
            frame.setSize(initalWidth, initalHeight);
        }
    });
}

//main panel to hold all others
public class TestPane extends JPanel {
    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        add(createLeftPane());
        add(createRightPane());
    }//end of class for master frame

    protected JPanel createLeftPane() {
        JLabel CharName = new JLabel("Character Name");
        CharName.setFont(new Font("Impact", Font.BOLD, 30));
        CharName.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 81,0, 00));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        content.setOpaque(false);

        JPanel view3D = new JPanel();
        view3D.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        JPanel view2D = new JPanel();
        view2D.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        JPanel viewIsometric = new JPanel();
        viewIsometric.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        JPanel viewData = new JPanel();
        viewData.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);

        JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        top.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 80,0, 80));
        top.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        top.add(view3D);
        top.add(view2D);

        JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 0));
        bottom.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 80,0, 80));
        bottom.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        bottom.add(viewIsometric);
        bottom.add(new JScrollPane(viewData));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.weighty = 0.5f;
        gbc.weightx = 1f;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        content.add(top, gbc);
        content.add(bottom, gbc);

        panel.add(content);
        panel.add(CharName, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        return  panel;
    }//end left pane

    protected JPanel createRightPane() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        //set up our image for the title bars
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("GradientDetail.png");
        Image img = icon.getImage();
        img = img.getScaledInstance(initalWidth/2, 40, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        final ImageIcon iconSM = new ImageIcon(img);

        JPanel name_panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout())
            {
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
                {
                //  Dispaly image at full size
                g.drawImage(iconSM.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
                super.paintComponent(g);
                }
            };
        name_panel.setOpaque( false );
        JLabel label = new JLabel(" Character Name");
        label.setFont(new Font("Impact", Font.BOLD, 30));
        label.setForeground(Color.white);
        label.setOpaque(false);
        JPanel name_panel_text = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        name_panel_text.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        name_panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(name_panel_text);
        panel.add(name_panel);
        return panel;
    }//end right pane

    //bassed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340001/determine-clicked-jpanel-component-in-the-mouselistener-event-handling
    public class MouseAdapterMod extends MouseAdapter {
       // usually better off with mousePressed rather than clicked
       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
           if (e.getSource() == "name_panel"){

           }
       }
    }
}//end master panel set
```

}//end master class

Comment: Is this GUI resizable?  If so, what does the GUI look like with extra width/height - where is the extra space assigned?

Comment: I suspect you main problem is that the two bottom panes have no preferred size...

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Good point.  You might also use `panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new BufferedImage(x,y,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB))));` to ***give*** it a preferred size.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ohh, sneaky :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something along the lines of ...

[image]

To be honest, I tried following your code, but got lost, so I re-wrote it...

Basically, you relying on `setSize` which is going to be ignored and changed by the layout managers as they see fit.

This example uses `GridBagLayout` and `weighty` to adjust the space allocated to the top (2D/3D) views and the bottom views, but you should also take a look at overriding the `getPreferredSize` of the final components, to provide better hints to the layout managers.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
            add(createLeftPane());
            add(createRightPane());

        }

        protected JPanel createLeftPane() {

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            panel.setBackground(Color.RED);

            JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            content.setOpaque(false);

            JPanel view3D = new JPanel();
            view3D.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            JPanel view2D = new JPanel();
            view2D.setBackground(Color.PINK);
            JPanel viewIsometric = new JPanel();
            viewIsometric.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            JPanel viewData = new JPanel();
            viewData.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);

            JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
            top.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN, 2));
            top.add(view3D);
            top.add(view2D);

            JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 0));
            bottom.add(viewIsometric);
            bottom.add(new JScrollPane(viewData));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weighty = 0.5f;
            gbc.weightx = 1f;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            content.add(top, gbc);
            content.add(bottom, gbc);

            panel.add(content);
            panel.add(new JLabel("Character name"), BorderLayout.NORTH);

            return  panel;

        }

        protected JPanel createRightPane() {

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

            return panel;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Wonderful, exactly what any Layout(build-in) lover would have used :-)

Comment: very, very nice! took it as my base and i'm tinkering with it to add the padding i want but thanks! is very nice and clean!