# Get clicked components in panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

I have a panel in which some components are added. They are classes that extend `JPanel` and JLabels
In my example 3+3 are placed but let's say there can be many of them.

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class MyPane {
 JFrame frame;
 JPanel panel;
 JPanel addpanel;

 public void createUI()
 {
    frame = new JFrame("Test clicks");
    panel = new JPanel();

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //ADD SMALLPANELS
    ArrayList<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<Color>();
    colorList.add(Color.red);
    colorList.add(Color.yellow);
    colorList.add(Color.blue);


    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
    String mytext="no"+ i;
    MyArea addpanel = new MyArea(mytext);
    addpanel.setBackground(colorList.get(i));

    panel.add(addpanel);
    }

    //ADD LABELS
    for (int i=0; i<4 ; i++){
    JLabel myLabel= new  JLabel();
    myLabel.setText("label"+ i);
    panel.add(myLabel);
    }

    //ADD INFORMATION LABEL
    JLabel MyTitle= new  JLabel();
    MyTitle.setText("You just clicked on:");
    MyTitle.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    MyTitle.setOpaque(true);
    panel.add(MyTitle);

 }  

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyPane overlapPane = new MyPane();
    overlapPane.createUI();
 }

 public class MyArea extends JPanel{
    public String areaname;

    public MyArea(String myname) {
        areaname=myname;
    }

 public String getAreaName() {
     return areaname;
 }
    }  
 }
```

What I want is, each time the user clicks on a component in the container, get the class of what is clicked. Then, depending on what is clicked, get some of its properties (JLabel text or `myarea` `areaname` and change the MyTitle caption. How can it be done?

Comment: Attach a MouseListener to your panel.

Comment: Use Java naming convention. Classes start with capital letters using `CamelCasing`

Comment: What I was asking was answered here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340001/determine-clicked-jpanel-component-in-the-mouselistener-event-handling][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340001/determine-clicked-jpanel-component-in-the-mouselistener-event-handling

Answer (score 5):

1. Use Java naming convention. Class names begin with capital letters using `CamelCasing` i.e. `MyArea`
2. **Don't** do this `JPanel addpanel = new myarea(..)`.  Why? Because `JPanel` does not have the methods `myarea` does.
   You should be doing this (*after correct naming convention*).

   ```
   MyArea addPanel = new MyArea(...);
   ```
3. Use `private` fields a getters

   ```
   public class MyArea extends JPanel {
       private String areaName;
       ...
       public String getAreaName() {
           return areaName;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add a `MouseListener` to the panel.

   ```
   private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
       @Override
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           MyArea source = (MyArea)e.getSource();
           String areaName = source.getAreaName();
           System.out.println(areaName);
       }
   }
   ....
   MyMouseListener listener = new MyMouseListener();
   for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
      String mytext="no"+ i;
      addpanel = new myarea(mytext);
      addPanel.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
      addpanel.setBackground(colorList.get(i));  
      panel.add(addpanel);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. What should I change if I don't know what is clicked? Maybe there are other things in the container such as JLabels. In that case MyArea source = (MyArea)e.getSource(); cannot work

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In the panel there are the myarea components and some other components such as Jlabels. What I need is when the user clicks on a myarea instance then he gets the areaName. When he click elsewhere nothing happens. When the mouse moves over a myarea the mouse changes to "hand" cursor. Actualy what you propose is adding a listener to the myarea. But maybe something should be added to the container that listens to what is clicked.

Comment: You can also override `mouseEntered` and do something when the mouse enters the panel. Also `mouseExited`

Comment: I unaccepted because I understood that I need something in the container that listents to what is clicked. Not in the component.

Comment: Nowhere in your original question do mention anything about what you're comment suggests. _"What I want is to click on a small panel (myarea panel) and get which panel was clicked. Then I could get any properties that panel has (such as areaname) How could I do it?"_

Answer (score 1):

Add a `MouseListener` to the panel.

```
    addpanel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            myarea panel = (myarea)e.getSource();
            //you can access the properties of the panel here
        }
    });
```